# Ajax wih CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to create 3 textfields with CI by using `form_input`. One is to enter the price, one is to enter the desired discount value, and the last one is for the discounted price which is calculated from price and discount value. How do I achieve it with CI? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wasn't able to fully understand the question since title says Ajax and in text you have not mentioned any ajax.

Well I'll explain how to use ajax with CodeIgniter. I'll be assuming u use JQuery and CodeIgntier.

Using Ajax with CodeIgniter is fairly simple. All you have to do is call the proper controller from Jquery.

for eg.

```
<input type="text" name="val1" />
<input type="text" name="val2" />
<input type="text" name="val3" id="val3" />
<input type="button" id="button" />
```

above is your view code
now jquery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
url: 'http://domain/index.php/controller',
...
...
success: function(val){
$('#val3').val(val);
}
});
});
```

in codeigniter controller you can fetch the values and return result as a number by echoing it.

```
function controller()
{
 $val1 = $this->input->post('val1');
 $val2 = $this->input->post('val2');
 echo $val1 + $val3;
}
```

Thats it.